# Java Try Catch NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying an example about try catch but it isn't working as I wanted. This is the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //This array's size is 5 and it has 4 Strings in it. 
    String[] array = new String[5];
    array[0] = "Hello";
    array[1] = "World";
    array[2] = "try catch";
    array[4] = "error";

    try
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i<array.length ; i++)
            System.out.println("This array has: "+array[i]);

    } catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Null!!!");
    }
}
```

output is like that :

> This array has: Hello
>
> This array has: World
>
> This array has: try catch
>
> This array has: null
>
> This array has: error

It supposed to enter catch block but it didn't. Any ideas?

Comment: What operation did you expect to throw the exception, and why? (Also, it would be appreciated if you could format your code carefully before posting - the indentation is all over the place here.)

Comment: array[3] is null and hence it prints that. Why should it throw an NPE?

Answer (score 7):

A `NullPointerException` occurs when a method is called on an object reference that is `null` or you attempt to access a `null` array.  But that doesn't occur here.  The array is initialized properly.  Even though you didn't initialize `array[3]`, the NPE doesn't occur here.

What does occur here is [String conversion (JLS, Section 5.1.11)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11).

> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).

A `null` `String` is converted to the `String` `"null"` when concatenated, so no NPE occurs.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of object arrays (all types except primitives) are initialized to `null`. When a `null` element is printed, the string literal "null" is displayed as shown in the below snippet of `PrintStream#print` used by `System.out.println`:

```
public void print(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        s = "null";
    }
    write(s);
}
```

Note that it's a bad practice to catch `NullPointerException`s. If it were a checked exception, the compiler would have probably flagged that the exception can never occur.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supposed to get into the 'catch' block.
there is no NullPointerException for REQUESTING array[i] even if it happens to hold null.
You will get an exception if you try to do anything with this null, e.g. array[i].toLowerCase()

Answer (score 0):

The elements of array are initialized as null.
If you want to get NullPointerException, try to use String methods like;

```
array[i].toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something with the string to create an error.

Do something like 'split(String regex)' this will cause the script to blow up cause you trying to split a null value. It will hit the catch portion of your script.